# Shared memory for several read-only objects with multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook, shared-memory, gensim

I am creating document vectors with a trained FastText model on my computer. Gensim's FastText, as far as I know, doesn't have an option to create document vectors (better known as Paragraph Vectors [PV]). Therefore I have calculated them manually by taking the average of the sum of the words available in a document. This task alone doesn't take as much time.

If I want to append several other numerical features to the calculated PV, 5 millionen docs take about 30 minutes to create. I thought this process could be improved by splitting the work onto several cores on my computer with the multiprocessing library of Python, which works right now but only to a certain extent.

There were a few problems I had to solve before getting to this stage. Since I am using the Jupyter Notebook to execute the code I had to place some methods in a seperate Python script to be able to use mulitprocessing in a Jupyter Notebook. This is the code that's available in the Jupyter Notebook. It imports the module "m_helpers" which has the methods to
create the document vectors:

```
import multiprocessing
import m_helpers

# Define number of workers.
num_processes = 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This pool spawns several processes to built the
    # document vectors with the FastText model
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes = num_processes, 
                              initializer = m_helpers.init_vars, 
                              initargs = (fasttext_model, vars_df)) as pool:
        results = pool.map(m_helpers.create_docvecs,
                           data_df.itertuples(name = False), 
                           chunksize = 512)
        output = [x for x in results]

    # Print length of output to see whether everything was processed
    print("Length of output (document vectors): {0}".format(len(output)))
```

m_helpers.py:

```
fasttext_model = None
vars_df = None

def init_vars(model, df):
    global fasttext_model
    fasttext_model = model
    global vars_df
    vars_df = df

def create_docvecs(data):
    word_vectors = [fasttext_model.wv[word] for word in data[-1].str.split()]
    document_vector = sum(word_vectors) / len(word_vectors)
    feature_vector = vars_df.loc[data[0], :].values
    # Further code to combine both vectors
    return document_vector
```

I have a computer with 6 cores / 12 threads. However I can make this code work only for 3 cores. Using more cores always results in an error caused by using up all the memory (RAM). I think this is caused by all those copies of objects for each process.

Now there seems to be ways to create a shared memory for all processes to access. There is a dataframe I am iterating over to access the text data. The method that is called for all processes uses an other dataframe and the fasttext model. All of those objects are read only to create the PV and append values from the other dataframe. I could merge the text dataframe and feature dataframe before. However, I would still need to share at least the fasttext_model object. So the question would be, how to do it? Is it possible at all? I have read several questions regarding this problem on stackoverflow but I couldn't make much out of it. Maybe I need to use something different than Pool?

Comment: you could try storing the dataframe in a database if it's really read-only

Comment: A very-similar question  (also by you?) was asked a couple weeks ago on the `gensim` project list. A few suggestions for "further optimizations" were made there that are still applicable: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/8t9zTRHQ9Xw/IE3RY5rVGAAJ

Comment: I have forgotten my account information. So I cannot log in anymore.
All the data should be in RAM already. One of my earlier approaches didn't have the `initializer` and `initargs` parameters. I would pass the available data to the m_helpers module with `intit_vars()` before I use `with multiprocessing.Pool()` statement. This approach resulted in errors where the started processes would report that the fasttext_model is None even though I have set those variables before.